# Flat video using google vr view

Tags: google-vr, 360-virtual-reality

Is there any way of making a flat view from a 360 video using Google's VR view player? I would like to see the full image without having to move.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you would like to see the full 'fisheye' view (Equirectangular projection), then if the video is a MP4 or being streamed as an mp4 most regular players will play it like that if you turn off the 360 view. The same is usually the case if the player does not support 360 view also - i.e. it will just display the flat fisheye view.